# How hexadecimal representation matches word size?

Tags: data-science, cpu-word

What does the statement "hexadecimal matches cleanly with modulo 8 word sizes, such as 8, 16, 32, and 64 bits" mean?

Comment: It means if you have a number in hex, you can break it up into groups of digits that each represent a separate word (where a word is some multiple of 8 bits). For instance, you can break it into pairs of digits, and each pair contains the data of one byte.

Answer (score 1):

Since a single hex digit can represent exactly 4 bits of binary data, any word size that's a multiple of 4 can be exactly represented with a fixed number of hex digits.

And every word size that's a multiple of 8 (i.e. the common ones) can be represented with a number of digits that's a multiple of 2:

- 8 bits can store values from 00 to FF
- 16 bits can store values from 0000 to FFFF
- 32 bits can store values from 00000000 to FFFFFFFF
- ...

All 2-digit hex numbers can be represented in 8 bits and all 8 bit values can be represented in 2 hex digits. If a hex editor displays some value as `CA FE BA BE` you can easily grasp that it's 4 bytes and thus 32 bits. Getting that information from the decimal 3405707966 is not quite as trivial (no matter how you group the digits: there's no nice "byte boundaries" in that representation).

If you compare this with decimal, the same isn't true. For example, 8 bits can represent values from 0 to 255 (decimal). So you need up to 3 digits in decimal to represent 8-bit values. But there are 3-digit decimal values that you can't represent in 8 bits: 256 (or anything higher than that) doesn't map onto 8 bits. So the mapping isn't perfect for decimal numbers.

Comment: So what does modulo mean in the statement as it is used to get the remainder.

Comment: "modulo 8 bit sizes" is a way of saying "bit sizes that divide by 8 with zero remainder" or simply "bit sizes that are divisible by 8".